# Splitting one record as multiple records in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

In python, how can I convert this data like this :

[image: 1]

into this data like this:

[image: 2]

Comment: Please include the code you've tried. Have your read these Excel files/csvs into pandas? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: He added tags such as `pandas` and `pandas-datareader`. I guess it must be pandas. I am not sure though. And the question is not clear. for example, Are those column names or length constant?

Comment: OP has added the `pandas` tag but didn't include any code. I asked if they've already **read** the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.split(..., 2, axis=1)` to split the dataframe vertically into 2 parts:

```
new_df = pd.concat([x.T.reset_index(drop=True).T for x in np.split(df.set_index('ID'), 2, axis=1)]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    0  1  2
ID         
1   0  1  0
1   1  1  1
2   1  1  0
2   0  0  1
3   1  1  1
3   1  0  1
4   1  0  1
4   0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:i+3].set_axis([*'XYZ'], axis=1) 
           for i in range(0,6,3)]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   X  Y  Z
1  0  1  0
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  1  1
3  1  0  1
4  1  0  1
4  0  1  0
```